# Bubble sort saving history of swaps not working

Tags: javascript, sorting

Developing a sorting visualiser using javascript.
I can't seem to save the swaps done each iteration in the swap history, the array swapHistory gets filled with the final output however if i console.log(output) that logsthe current iteration??
I'm utterly baffled by this

```
bubbleSort = (input) => {
    startTime = performance.now();
    var output = input;
    swapHistory = [];
    swaps = 0;
    let swap = false;
    do {
        swap = false;
        output.forEach((current, i) => {
            if (current > output[i + 1]) {
                const temp = current;
                console.log(current);
                console.log(output[i + 1]);
                console.log(output);
                swapHistory.push(output);
                output[i] = output[i + 1];
                output[i + 1] = temp;
                swaps++;
                swap = true;
            }
        });
    } while (swap);
    endTime = performance.now();
    timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
    console.log(timeTaken);
    setArray(output);
    $("#timeTaken").html("Time taken: " + timeTaken.toFixed(4) + "ms");
};
```

Expecting the swapHistory array to be filled with each iteration of swaps

Comment: What is `setArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're pushing the `output` array itself to the `swapHistory` array, when you mean to be pushing the current value of `output` to `swapHistory`. Essentially, you're passing by reference when you want to be passing by value.

Easy fix here is to clone the `output` array and save that in `swapHistory`, rather than a reference to the `output` array itself. So, change `swapHistory.push(output);` to `swapHistory.push(output.slice());`, as slice with no parameters is just a quick way to clone an array.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense now. :)